# How to limit the number of characters entered by a user in EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want the user to enter only one character in the EditText field.So, if he tries to enter a string the program should not allow it and limit it to only one character.How can i achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

from layout add attribute

```
android:maxLength="1"
```

or from code

```
TextEdit te = findViewById(...);
te.setFilters( new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1) } )
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `maxLength` attribute in `EditText`. Just set it to `1`:

```
<EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="1"/>
```